# When one blows up a latex balloon, why does it get easier to blow once it has a little air in it (after 1 or 2 breaths)?

Tags: classical-mechanics, air, elasticity

When one blows up a latex balloon, why does it get easier to blow once it has a little air in it (after 1 or 2 breaths)?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is filling a balloon from your mouth much harder initially?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122505/)

Comment: Because the tensile strength of the balloon skin reduces when you start to inflate the balloon. I agree with Brock Adams in the possible duplicate.

Comment: Thanks.  Can u migrate it?  Sorry for that!