# "Internal (hydrostatic) pressure" in a stretched rubber membrane

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

In the ["Two-balloon experiment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-balloon_experiment#Theoretical_pressure_curve) Wikipedia article the James-Guth stress-strain relation includes an "internal (hydrostatic) pressure" $p$ (this is not the same as the air pressure $P$ in the balloon). They derive that, as the membrane is stretched, $p$ starts at some positive value and decreases as the square of the thickness.

Is $p$ an actual physical pressure that could somehow be measured inside a chunk of rubber?

Comment: I think $p$ is air pressure inside balloon. I think their derivation is saying that thinner the balloon lower the air pressure required to achieve equilibrium.

Comment: @Zero No, the expression they derive for $P$ (beside the graph) is different.

Comment: Is the rubber being treated as incompressible in the rheological constitutive equation that you are using?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Not in the equation itself. From what they say it is an additional assumption. BTW, the Wiki is closely based on the cited article [The pressure curve for a rubber balloon](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/46/10/10.1119/1.11486), viewable [here](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/50891405/the-pressure-curve-for-a-rubber-balloon-loreto-unican).

Comment: I don't have access to the article.  What is the rheological equation they are using?  I guess the balloon is assumed to be a perfect sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked over the James-Guth analysis, which assumes that the rubber is incompressible and obeys a certain specific constitutive equation.  This means that the principal stresses in the material are  determined up to an arbitrary constant, which is typically denoted with the symbol p.  As for any problem involving incompressibility of the material, the value of the "pressure" p must be determined by applying the boundary conditions.  The state of stress in the rubber is considered as "plane stress," which means that the stress in the thickness direction is negligible compared to the hoop stresses in the rubber.  From this, the p value is determined by setting the thickness stress equal to zero.

Here is an analysis I did a while back (post #4) of balloon expansion for a material of arbitrary elastic constitutive behavior that you may find of value:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/hookes-law-for-a-balloon.670566/#post-4264407

Comment: Thanks. There is also the Question [Why is filling a balloon from your mouth much harder initially?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122505/why-is-filling-a-balloon-from-your-mouth-much-harder-initially/295688#295688).

Comment: Are you asking what I think about this?

Comment: I think your PF analysis would be a better answer for that question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the balloon inflation question, if I use the well-known Mooney-Rivlin constitutive equation for rubber for this problem (assuming incompressible), I get a relationship for the pressure difference across the balloon membrane that is very similar to the James-Guth result:

$$P=\frac{4h_0}{r_0}\frac{C_1}{\lambda}\left(1+\frac{C_2}{C_1}\lambda^2\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{\lambda^6}\right)$$where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are material constants, $h_0$ is the initial rubber thickness, $r_0$ is the initial radius, and $\lambda$ is the rubber stretch ratio $r/r_0$.

Comment: That appears to increase for large $\lambda$. I guess if $C_2/C_1$ is small that would only happen beyond the range of applicability of Mooney-Rivlin?

Comment: I think that would have to be correct.